# Differences between LIBS over LA-ICP-MS?

Tags: spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry, geochemistry

Which differences should I consider between the techniques Laser-Induced Breakdown Spectroscopy and Laser Ablation Inductively Coupled Plasma Mass Spectrometry for a geochemistry fingerprint focused research?

Both use Laser Ablation for particle generation and analysis, so the sample preparation step is minimal in both instruments, but I would like to know about the instrument costs, the cuantification limits if apply and the advantages that offer each one.

Comment: I think this question might be a bit too broad. One thing that might narrow it down is knowing a bit more about the sort of geochemical materials you will be using these machines on. @CristhianParedes